# About sendMessage to another background app

Tags: python, c++, pywin32, win32com, win32gui

I have got the target app's "hwnd".
And use "hwnd" to get thread id & process id.
And use "thread id" to get more datail info: "cbSize","flags","hwndActive","hwndFocus","hwndCapture","hwndMenuOwner","hwndMoveSize","hwndCaret","rcCaret".

If I want send message to a "notepad" app, I have to get the "child hwnd" from notepad's hwnd which name is "EDIT", and send message to it.

```
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(notepadHwnd, callback, hwnds)
// callback make the hwnds.
// hwnds is a key-value object about "child hwnd text" : hwnd
win32api.SendMessage(hwnds["EDIT]", win32con.WM_CHAR, ord('1'), 0)
```

It's worked.

If I want send message to "chrome" app, I can just use chrome's hwnd to do it:

```
win32api.SendMessage(chromeHwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x31, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.SendMessage(chromeHwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x31, 0)
```

It's worked.

And now, I want to send message to some "Game" app, like: Super Mario(use VirtuaNES) or Final Fantasy (use ePSXe). I send message to "hwnd" or "hwndFocus" or "threadId":

```
// send to VirtuaNES Hwnd
win32api.SendMessage(nesHwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x31, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.SendMessage(nesHwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x31, 0)

// send to VirtuaNES hwndFocus
win32api.SendMessage(hwndFocus, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x31, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.SendMessage(hwndFocus, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x31, 0)

//send to VirtuaNES thread id
win32api.PostThreadMessage(threadId, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 0x31, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.PostThreadMessage(threadId, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 0x31, 0)
```

It always no work.

How to send message to those app?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (or `SendMessage()`, either). Use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) or better [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau SendInput() seems like I use code to press keyboard, so I need to focus window at the game app and run script, right?
Is there some way to send keyboard event to a app even I minimize it?